# Creating a third column from a function on the first two in Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy, lambda

I have a function:

```
def lookup(group, name):
    try:
        #sql query with group and name
        return answer
    except:
        return 'NULL'
```

And a pandas Dataframe:

```
+------------+------+
|   group    | name |
+------------+------+
| redteam    | paul |
| blueteam   | pat  |
| yellowteam | mike |
+------------+------+
```

I want to feed the group and name of each row into my 'lookup' function, and return the answer for the row as a cell in a 3rd column: 'value'

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493086/compare-values-in-2-columns-and-output-the-result-in-a-third-column-in-pandas) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440068/comparing-two-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-to-create-a-third-one) question. but they're not quite what I'm doing.

I've also looked at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914937/applying-function-with-multiple-arguments-to-create-a-new-pandas-column) question. Which IS what I'm doing. but it also didn't succeed for me.

I've tried this:
`df['value'] = lookup(df[0],df[1])`
and this:
`df['value'] = df.apply(lambda x: lookup(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)`

but it just makes the value column all 'NULL'

Any suggestions from here are much appreciated.

Comment: is group the index of the dataframe or just a column?

Comment: group is just a column. It's a 2-column dataframe.

Comment: why are you using df[0] df[1], is that the name of the columns? or group and name are the columns name... what df.columns gives you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to test without a good reproducible example but you can try this,
assuming that group is not the index of the dataframe:

here is a full scale example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2), columns=['group', 'name'])

def lookup(group, name):
    if group > 0.4:
        return 'YES'
    else:
        return 'NULL'

df['value'] = df.apply(lambda x: lookup(x['group'], x['name']), axis=1)

df
      group      name value
0  0.088522  0.221607  NULL
1  0.366478  0.612860  NULL
2  0.018939  0.995080  NULL
3  0.143422  0.590115  NULL
4  0.747373  0.888054   YES
5  0.960380  0.586448   YES
6  0.671776  0.151144   YES
7  0.632334  0.802551   YES
8  0.041953  0.387241  NULL
9  0.557183  0.199470   YES
```

Comment: Steven, thanks this worked great! Turns out I was forgetting to pass the cursor to the sql statement, and that's why I was getting the 'NULL' return of the function. That said, I think that now makes this question a duplicate